# Inserting an image in SVG dynamically does not display

Tags: javascript, svg

I am using Chrome and I have an example with the following code:

```
<svg width="2000" height="800" id="canvas" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <image xlink:href="icons/remove.svg" height="200" width="200" x="0" y="0"></image>
</svg>
```

This is rendered correctly.

When I produce the very same image tag using Javascript the image is not displayed. Looking at the network tab it seems it is not retrieved from the server.

### Edit following comments

Code used to add the svg image:

```
  let svg = document.getElementById('canvas');

  let boxSide = 200;
  const svgns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
  let x = 0;
  let y = 0;
  let element = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'image');
  element.setAttribute("xlink:href", "icons/remove.svg");
  element.setAttribute("width", boxSide.toString());
  element.setAttribute("height", boxSide.toString());
  element.setAttribute("x", "0");
  element.setAttribute("y", "0");
  svg.appendChild(element);
```

Let me stress again that the DOM looks exactly the same as the one created statically, which display correctly

Comment: I suspect you may use createElement instead of `createElementNS` and / or setAttribute instead of `setAttributeNS`. If this doesn't help please add your javascript code to the question.

Comment: @enxaneta done but please note that the DOM looks the same when generated dynamically or created statically

Comment: @FedericoTomassetti xlink:href needs to be created with setAttributeNS

Comment: @RobertLongson you are right, that fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating a namespaced element with `createElementNS`, you need to use `element.setAttributeNS` instead of `element.setAttribute`.

Try this:

```
let svg = document.getElementById('canvas');

let boxSide = 200;

const svgns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
let element = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'image');

element.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', 'icons/remove.svg');
element.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', boxSide.toString());
element.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', boxSide.toString());
element.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', '0');
element.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', '0');
svg.appendChild(element);
```